# Error while installation of Apache httpd 2.4.2 on AIX OS

Tags: apache, gcc, aix

We are getting below error while running the make command to build Apache files.
We are carrying out the installation on AIX 6.1 OS.
The installation is completed upto the configuration step as per the procedure given in the below link:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

The error is :

```
util_pcre.c:48:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
util_pcre.c: In function 'ap_regfree':
util_pcre.c:103: error: 'pcre_free' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:103: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
util_pcre.c:103: error: for each function it appears in.)
util_pcre.c: In function 'ap_regcomp':
util_pcre.c:129: error: 'PCRE_CASELESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:131: error: 'PCRE_MULTILINE' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:133: error: 'PCRE_DOTALL' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:136: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pcre_compile'
util_pcre.c:136: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
util_pcre.c:142: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pcre_fullinfo'
util_pcre.c:142: error: expected ')' before 'pcre'
util_pcre.c:142: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'type name'
util_pcre.c:143: error: 'PCRE_INFO_CAPTURECOUNT' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c: In function 'ap_regexec_len':
util_pcre.c:180: error: 'PCRE_NOTBOL' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:182: error: 'PCRE_NOTEOL' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:198: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pcre_exec'
util_pcre.c:198: error: expected ')' before 'pcre'
util_pcre.c:198: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'type name'
util_pcre.c:221: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:223: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:225: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_BADOPTION' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:227: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_BADMAGIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:229: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_UNKNOWN_NODE' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:231: error: 'PCRE_ERROR_NOMEMORY' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.
```

We have also installed the below version GCC compiler for AIX 6.1:-

```
libgcc-4.2.0-3.aix6.1.ppc.rpm
libstdcplusplus-4.2.0-3.aix6.1.ppc.rpm
libstdcplusplus-devel-4.2.0-3.aix6.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-cplusplus-4.2.0-3.aix6.1.ppc.rpm
```

Kindly suggest as to what is missing here that is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't miss `pcre` if you installed `pcre`... http://www.pcre.org/

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy : We have already installed the pcre. But still facing same issues.

Comment: Guess you have installed `pcre` from rpm-package, haven't you? Then also install package `pcre-devel`. ftp://www.oss4aix.org/RPMS/pcre/

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy : On provided url, there is no pcre available for AIX 6.1. Please suggest which version of pcre do we need to install on AIX 6.1 OS.

Comment: rpm packages for _older_ AIX versions can be installed without problems. Where from did you install `pcre` on the first place?

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy : I have downloaded the pcre-8.30.tar.gz from http://www.pcre.org . Please suggest.

Comment: I would suggest downloading `pcre-8.41` from there, then compiling and installing it.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy : Still getting same error after installation of pcre-8.41. Please suggest.

Comment: If anyone have done this before please let me know ASAP.

Comment: (off)You could try opening a topic here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/aix-43/